# How to remove part of the string before specific word using grok or gsub in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, gsub, logstash-grok, grok

I have a string field "origin_message". It is pretty big one (used multiline to get mail content. Example of "origin_message":

```
Delivered-to: somemail@domain.com A LOT OF OTHER CONTENT Subject: Subject goes here AND THE REST OF THE MESSAGE
```

Desired result:

```
Subject goes here AND THE REST OF THE MESSAGE
```

Is there a way to trim everything before "Subject:" phrase?

I have tried the following filter with no luck:

```
filter {
mutate {
    add_field => { "original_message" => "%{message}" }
    convert => {
        "original_message" => "string"
    }

    gsub => [
        "original_message", "^(.*)Subject", " "
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Using `gsub` is correct. When I use this pattern `"^(.*)Subject:"`, I get the following output `"  Subject goes here AND THE REST OF THE MESSAGE"`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work in my case. Probably that is because of multiline code being used to input data? I still have full original message.

Comment: But by the time the event hits the `gsub` filter, everything is on one line, right?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out now. Not sure if it is one line, but it is one string field for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sure why but using gsub on "message" field before copying that to separate "original_message" field fixed the issue.

```
filter {
mutate {
    gsub => ["message", "^(.*)Subject", " "]
    add_field => { "original_message" => "%{message}" }

    convert => {
        "original_message" => "string"
    }
}
}
```

@Val, thanks for verification. Issue appeared to be not pattern related.